# what's the difference between pthread_attr_setschedparam and pthread_setschedparam?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix, scheduling

what's the difference between pthread_attr_setschedparam and pthread_setschedparam?   How should I make decision to choose one to use?

Comment: What about reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_setschedparam()` sets both the scheduler policy and scheduler parameters for an existing thread.

`pthread_attr_setschedparam()` and `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy()` set the scheduler parameters and scheduler policy respectively for a *thread attributes object* (type `pthread_attr_t`).  This will set the scheduler parameters and scheduler policy for any new threads that are then created using that thread attributes object (eg. you can pass a thread attributes object as the second parameter of `pthread_create()`).

So which one you want to use depends on whether you want to set the scheduler policy / parameters of an existing thread, or a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

The naming is confusing but they are for different purposes.

`pthread_setschedparam` is for setting the parameter of the thread

`pthread_attr_setschedparam` is for setting the attributes of the parameter of the thread.

Which means that

- If you want to set a specific attribute you have to use
  `pthread_attr_setschedparam`
- And if you want the set the specific parameter for the tread you have
  to use  `pthread_setschedparam`

Comment: No, this is not right - you do not have to use both.  You use one or the other depending on whether you want to change the scheduler parameters of a thread or of a thread attributes object.

Comment: @caf You could use both as well right? start by using the thread attribute object and then for instance, change the priority dynamically for an existing thread using `pthread_setschedparam()`